# How to transfer materials with a scene created in Blender to unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I have created a scene in Blender with multiple objects, and each object has a material/texture. When I save the scene in my assets of my Unity project, I am able to use the scene, but all of the objects are white and have lost the materials I created and added to them in Blender. Is there a way to save my scene in Blender so that the materials will also be saved to the objects for when I use the scene in Unity? Or do I need to save all the materials from Blender separately into a file and also put that in my assets folder?

Comment: Do you use the node editor of Blender in order to make your materials (using Cycles render engine if I'm not wrong) ? AFAIK, these materials can't be exported. Only the "simple" materials can be retrieved in Unity. You have to do all the major part of the rendering aspect job inside Unity.

Comment: Ah dang, yeah I used the node editor with the cycles render engine. Guess I'll have to just redo it all in unity lol

Comment: @jp3434 No, it isn't that bad, you can just bake out your Cycles materials...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hellium said, if your textures are in separate archives (.png) you can create materials in unity and add those png textures as albedo